# Hibernate Many to one in cascade delete

Tags: hibernate

Hello everyone i am new to this group.i have a problem in many to one relationship.i had table called machinemaster in which ther is one primary key & there are 12 other table say bios,hdd & so on in this all tables have the refernce of machinemaster say machineID.at first data will be inserted in machinemaster & after taking the refernce of id it will be inserted to all child tables..it works fine...but when i enter the data in child table it make null to all the field of machinemaster except id...so wat going wrong that i dnt knw...has there is problem in cascade=delete & lazy=false...i had kept this so tell me is this right if yes then why the parent data is update to null when i insert the data in child based on the refernce of parent...thanks in advance

Comment: publish your hbm mappings and try to format the question little bit.

Answer (score 0):

i would go with a inheritance hierarchy like this

```
class Part
{
    int id;
}

class Hdd extends Part
{
    string someProp;
}

class Bios extends Part
{
    string version;
}

<class name="Part" table="mashinemaster">
  <id name="id" >
    <generator ...>
  </id>
  <joined-subclass name="Hdd" table="hddtable">
    <key column="machineID" />
    <property name="someProp" />
  </joined-subclass>
  <joined-subclass name="Bios" table="biostable">
    <key column="machineID" />
    <property name="version" />
  </joined-subclass>
</class>
```